# Using one array to track 3 pieces of data

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I need your help with using one array to track 3 pieces of data. I have o use one array because it is school assignment and I am required to do so. 
The array has to track Province ID, Region ID and the population for each region. There is 13 province and in each province there is 48 regions. Since the array is fixed size, I used a 624 by 3 multi dimensional array. The first column is for the provinceID, the second is for the regionID, and the third one is for the population.. I set the rows to 624 because there is 13 province and 48 regions in each province so 13*48 = 624.

I was able to insert my data and display them like this

```
ProvinceID # 1 RegionID # 1: 125000
```

Instead I would like to display the regions and population by province.

Something like this:

```
ProvinceID #1

RegionID # 1: 12000
RegionID # 2: 30000

ProvinceID #2

RegionID #1: 14000
RegionID #: 145000
```

Here is what I did
I declare a global array 
     int[,] census;

I initialize it on form initialize
     census = new int[624,3];

Here is my insert

```
try
{
    // declare variables
    int prov, region, population;

    prov = Convert.ToInt32(txtProvinceID.Text);
    region = Convert.ToInt32(txtRegionID.Text);
    population = Convert.ToInt32(txtPopulation.Text);


    census[counter, 0] = prov;
    census[counter, 1] = region;
    census[counter, 2] = population;

    counter++;

    MessageBox.Show("Population " + txtPopulation.Text.ToString() + " saved for Province #" + txtProvinceID.Text.ToString()
        + " , Region #" + txtRegionID.Text.ToString(), "Success!");

    txtRegionID.Clear();
    txtProvinceID.Clear();
    txtPopulation.Clear();
    txtProvinceID.Focus();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message == "Input string was not in a correct format.")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a numeric value", "Error");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

This is the code to retrieve the data and save them to a file

```
string output = "";

try
{
    for (int rows = 0; rows < census.GetLength(0); rows++)
    {

        for (int columns = 0; columns < census.GetLength(1); columns++)
        {
            if (census[rows, columns] != 0)
            {
                if (columns == 0)
                {
                    output += "Province ID #" + census[rows, columns];
                }
                else if (columns == 1)
                {
                    output += "Region ID #" + census[rows, columns] + ": ";
                }
                else if (columns == 2)
                {
                    output += census[rows, columns] + "\n";
                }

            }// END if census[rows, coloumns]!=0

        }// END for coloumns

    }//END for(int row =0

    // save the data to a text file

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
    sfd.FileName = "untitled";
    sfd.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|Word Doc (*.doc)|*.doc";
    sfd.DefaultExt = "txt";
    sfd.AddExtension = true;
    sfd.ShowDialog();

    FileStream sf = new FileStream(sfd.FileName, FileMode.Create);

    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(sf);

    sw.Write(output);

    sw.Close();
}
catch (Exception)
{

}
```

Comment: please provide some code for your try!

Comment: @user2589904 why dont you use a database to store these values?

Comment: @Nithin Nayagam  It is school assignment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of a table in which the rows are provinces and the columns are regions. And in each table cell is the population for that province/region. It would look like this

```
            Region 1    Region 2    Region 3
Province 1   12000       13000       14000
Province 2   11320        9876        1234
Province 3   19723       32767        5038
Province 4     263        1284        1961
```

This exactly corresponds to a two-dimensional array:

```
int[,] census = new int[4,3];
```

And the values in the array would be, for example:

```
census[0,0] = 12000;  // Province 1, Region 1
census[0,1] = 13000;  // Province 1, Region 2
census[2,2] = 5038;   // Province 3, Region 3
```

Modifying your code, you'd create your census array as:

```
int[,] census = new int[13, 48];
```

And to populate it:

```
prov = Convert.ToInt32(txtProvinceID.Text);
region = Convert.ToInt32(txtRegionID.Text);
population = Convert.ToInt32(txtPopulation.Text);
census[prov-1, region-1] = population;
```

Now, if you want to output by province and region:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int prov = 0; prov < census.GetLength(0); prov++)
{
    output.AppendLine("Province ID " + prov+1);
    for (int region = 0; region < census.GetLength(1); ++region)
    {
        output.AppendLine("  Region #" + region+1 + " " +
            census[prov, region]);
    }
}
```

And then to output it, you open the file as you showed and `Write(output.ToString())`.

I used `StringBuilder` to construct the output rather than appending to a `string`. Appending strings is very expensive.

Also, you can simplify your file writing you using [File.WriteAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext.aspx), like this:

```
// Show the Save File dialog box. And then,
File.WriteAllText(sfd.Filename, output.ToString());
```

There's no need to open a `FileStream` and then a `StreamWriter`. `File.WriteAllText` takes care of all that for you.

### Update

To skip provinces that have no data, you write to a temporary `StringBuilder` and then append that to the final output only if there is data. For example:

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
for (int prov = 0; prov < census.GetLength(0); prov++)
{
    StringBuilder sbTemp = new StringBuilder();
    for (int region = 0; region < census.GetLength(1); ++region)
    {
        if (census[prov, region] != 0)
        {
            sbTemp.AppendLine("  Region #" + region+1 + " " +
                census[prov, region]);
        }
    }
    if (sbTemp.Length > 0)
    {
        // At least one region had population, so add that
        // and the province to the output.
        output.AppendLine("Province ID " + prov+1);
        output.Append(sbTemp);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does what I am looking for:) I had to remove the -1 because prove and region id start from 0.. There is one more thing I would like to know how to achieve. How do I make it not to out put the province line if there is no input under that province? I know how to do it for the region if(census[prov, region]!=0){} but what about the province?

Comment: @user2589904: Generate the output for each province into a temporary `StringBuilder`, keeping a sum of the populations of the regions in that province. When you're done generating for that province, check the sum. If it's greater than 0, then copy the temporary output to the final output. Make sense?

Comment: I tried but I got repeated records... I don't know what I did wrong

Comment: perfect... Thank you so much for your help.. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

> The array has to track Province ID, Region ID and the population for each region.

This indicates that you should create a `class` to hold the three pieces of data. This way, it will be much easier to work with the array. Something like:

```
class Region
{
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }
    public int RegionId { get; set; }
    public long Population { get; set; }
}
```

Notice that I chose a different type for population, you wouldn't be able to do this with a simple array and you're certainly going to need something like that sooner or later.

When you have that, you can use LINQ to create groups of regions from the same province:

```
Region[] regions = …; // or maybe List<Region>

var regionGroups = regions.GroupBy(r => r.ProvinceId);

var result = new StringBuilder();

foreach (regionGroup in regionGroups)
{
    result.AppendFormat("Province ID #{0}\n\n", regionGroup.Key);

    foreach (var region in regionGroup)
    {
        result.AppendFormat(
            "Region ID #{0}: {1}\n", region.RegionId, region.Population);
    }
}

return result.ToString();
```

---

Also, you should never ever do this:

```
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

If you need to handle some specific exceptions, handle those, but *only those*.

Comment: As I said, this is a school assignment, and I am required to do it using one array and nothing else... I can't use LINQ or any other options... If it was not a school assignment, I would look for other options like using a database to store the data or use lists or something else.

Comment: @user2589904 If you really can't use an array of classes, then that's a bad assignment.

Comment: Not a bad assignment at all. This is a pretty standard introductory type of assignment that shows how to use multidimensional arrays for directly indexed data.

Comment: @JimMischel I think it is a bad assignment, because it promotes bad practices. Multidimensional arrays should be used when all the values are of the same logical type, not when one is id and another one is population.

Comment: @svick all of the input are of the same data type.. we only stored the population in the array, and the purpose of this assignment is to teach the students the different types of the arrays, how to create them , initialize them and retrieve data from them.

Comment: The array only holds one type of data: the population. It's indexed by Province ID and Region ID, both of which are integers. This is no different than an MxN matrix of floats that's indexed by row and column. It's a *perfect* application of a multidimensional array.

Comment: @JimMischel You're right, I didn't think of that. I was going by the way the array was used in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is really difficult to do this with your current program design

i suggest you to use jagged arrays for storing the values since **LINQ can not be used on 2D arrays**

A jagged array is an "array of arrays"

```
string[][] census=new string[624][];

for(int i=0;i<624;i++)
{
census[i]=new string[3];
}
```

Now you can use LINQ to get the required data from the array

```
var match=from c in census 
          where c[0]=="Province ID Text"
          from details in c
          where details!="Province ID Text"
          select details;
```

and print the values as follows

```
foreach(var i in match)
Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: Is there a way to display the data like I mentioned above using the jagged array but without using LINQ? as I said, this is a school assignment and I am not supposed to use LINQ... If it was not school assignment, I would use database to store the data.

Comment: @user2589904 are you atleast allowed to use List<>?

Comment: No, we are not allowed to use list.. we are restricted to use jagged array or multidimensional array at this point for learning purposes, and later one we will be using list<>

Comment: @user2589904 check my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really particular on NOT using objects or database tables to store the values and 
also don't want to use LINQ, the following solution might help you

```
        void Select(string key)
        {
            for(int i=0;i<624;i++)
            {
                if(census[i][0]==key)
                {
                    Console.Write(census[i][1]);
                    Console.Write(census[i][2]);
                    Console.WriteLine();

                }

            }
        }
```

To eliminate duplicate data, we use a List to check whether that Province Id was previously checked or not

```
            string done = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < 624; i++)
            {
                if (!done.Contains(census[i][0]))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(census[i][0]);
                    Select(census[i][0]);
                }
                done=done+census[i][0];
            }
```

I hope this code helps you but this is really NOT a good way to program.